# How to retrieve the rest api complete response in vugen?

Tags: json, rest, api, loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to retrieve the complete json response in VUGEN. I am new to writing script in VUGEN. I am using web-HTTP/HTML protocol and just wrote a simple script to call a rest service with POST.

Action()
{

```
web_rest("POST: http://losthost:8181/DBConnector/restServices/cass...",
    "URL=http://losthost:8181/DBConnector/restServices/oep_catalog_v1",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=raw",
    "Snapshot=t868726.inf",
    HEADERS,
    "Name=filter", "Value=upc=123456789", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=env", "Value=qa", ENDHEADER,
    LAST);

return 0;
```

}

I don't know what to do next. I searched on the internet to get any command to pull response value. I got web_reg_save_param but it just pulls one value. I need the complete response saved in a file or string.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VuGen provides several APIs to extract response data.
For example, you can do the boundary based correlation with empty left and right boundary. The sample below saves the web_rest response (body of donuts.js) in the parameter CorrelationParameter3.

```
web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=CorrelationParameter3",
    "LB=",
    "RB=",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    LAST);

web_rest("GET: donuts.js",
    "URL=http://adobe.github.io/Spry/data/json/donuts.js",
    "Method=GET",
    "Snapshot=t769333.inf",
    LAST);
```

This process of locating, extracting and replacing dynamic values is called “correlation”.
You can read more about correlations in [LoadRunner correlations kept simple](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/LoadRunner-correlations-kept-simple/ba-p/237712#.WghRIGiCyF4)  blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is helpful :)This will at least get me started with something.

Comment: You are welcome.
If this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your manager owes your training and a mentor for a period if you are asked to perform in this capacity

Comment: Thank you :) I am doing this out of my own interest to learn.

Comment: Download and take the tutorial